# Ideological rebus

Tags: knowledge, rebus, language, geography, movies

The answers form one word.

#1

> [image]

#2

> [image]

#3

> [image]

#4

> [image]

Hint for #3:

> "SLC" could equally well be "NYC".

---

<sub>Image credits:

clue 1 #1: dtstuff9, CC-BY-SA 2.0

clue 1 #2: See Li, CC-BY-SA 2.0

clue 1 #3: Mingle Media TV, CC-BY-SA 2.0

clue 1 #4: Eva Rinaldi, CC-BY-SA 2.0

clue 2: Kremlin.ru, CC-BY 4.0

clue 4 #1: JL 09, CC-BY-SA 3.0

clue 4 #2: Itub, CC-BY SA 3.0</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For #1

> As pointed by @MOehm this is the list of the [Academy award winners for best actress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_Award_for_Best_Actress) between 2005 and 2008. The missing one is 2007, Marion Cotillard. In this case we get **RA**.

For #2

> I think it's a play on word with a bit of Russian language. Rasputin = Ras Putin, which sounds in Russian like once (or one) Putin, then we have dva (two) Putin, tri (three) Putin. the second image is framed. So I guess it's **D**VAPUT**I**N, which gives us letters **DI**.

For #3  Thanks to @MOehm

> This is the flag of Mexico. The hint points out that SLC is a city. Only the last letter is red so from MEXICO we get XY MEXI and then we need a city that starts like that and ends with CALI. [MEXICALI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexicali) fits the description. Than for the middle part we get just [CALI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cali) and the last bit is CALI + CO or XICO and [CALEXICO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calexico,_California) (almost) fits the requirement. This leads us to **CALI**

For #4

> This is Samar island, part of the Phillippines and the Periodic table. I guess the word from this one is the element Samarium. As suggested by @ibrahimmahrir the letters must **SM**, the symbolic name of samarium.

The 'ideological' word we are looking therefore will end with:

> So we get RA-DI-*-SM and considering the current situation of the world I guess it's **RA-DI-CALI-SM**.

Comment: I think #4 is just the two letters $ \color{white}{SM}$ (select to reveal).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, thank you, I've already used your advice.

Comment: Personally, I think your 2 and 4 are correct rather than your 1 & 3, but that's just my opinion...

Comment: @El-Guest I agree. I haven't used the movies tag and also I don't think the answer for 3 is correct either. It just sort of fits.

Comment: rot13(V guvax sbe PNYV vg pbhyq unir fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu gur fgngr bs Onwn Pnyvsbeavn va Zrkvpb (juvpu va ratyvfu jbhyq or Fgngr bs Ybjre Pnyvsbeavn, juvpu svgf gur FYP vavgvnyf), naq gur fgngr vf *vafvqr* Zrkvpb.)

Comment: Your number 1 is correct, but the reasoning is different, I think: Look at MMVII [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_Award_for_Best_Actress).

Comment: (As for #3, I'm not very convinced by the SLC explanation. I think that the halvles of the flag refer to the beginning and end of that country's name, so that we get [a word that begins like it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexicali) and [a word that ends like it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calico). The solution _xyz_ is then the common part with the Same Letter Count. Well, I'm not super-convinced of that either, but it kinda works.)

Comment: #1, #2 and #4 are correct, as is your overall answer. I have posted a hint for #3.

Comment: Hmm. I'll refine my comment above and throw out this: The red C only hints at the nature of the three words in the first line, namely [beginning of flag's country + xyz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexicali), [xyz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cali) and [most of xyz + end of flag's country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calexico,_California). (Look closely at the third xyz.)